# Best suitable hashbyte algorithm for SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2016, sha256, hashbytes

I have source table with 399 columns in SQL Server 2008 R2.

I want to add one more column with hashbyte on above table and store on the database which is SQL Server 2016 using SSIS package.

PS - I can't ask source owner to upgrade his/her SQL Server to 2016 hence could not use SHA2_256. also few points are :
 1. There are couple of tables having more than 200 columns, and one is having 
    exact 399 columns.
 2. I had use MD5 algorithm, but I read MD5 might give you deprecated value in 
    SQL 2016. Hence it is advisable to use only SHA2_256 or SHA2_512. 
 3. About the code, its simple truncate and load into destination tables with 
    some transformations. 
 4. I am using HASH to identify entire row for update or insert as CHECKSUM is 
    not reliable.

Comment: What criteria are you using for "best"? This feels rather opinion-based. Do you have some example code that readers can use as a baseline for your question?

Comment: Aside: why do you have a table with 399 columns? That sounds like it could do with some urgent refactoring!

Comment: Here's a list of algorithms built into SQL Server . Why don't you read this and give us some reasons why these aren't suitable. I'm going to guess the purpose of the hash is to identify an entire row, not for security reasons. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2988/understanding-the-sql-server-hashbytes-hashing-algorithms/

Comment: What, aside from a single password column are you wanting to hash?